# Get the textarea contents in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a text area. And i have to get the contents of the text area using Tkinter in python.

```
self.outputText = Text(self)
self.outputText.place(relx = 0, rely = 0.15, relwidth = 1, relheight = 0.7)
self.outputText.insert(index = INSERT, chars = textParam)
```

Comment: Perhaps the [get](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.get-method) method can help you get there.

Comment: @Kevin: I used self.outputText.get(1.0,END) but its is not working

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: @Kevin: Not working even after making changes as below

Comment: @Kevin:_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".48686248.48687816"

Answer (score 0):

The way to get the data out of the text widget is with the `get` method. Tkinter always guarantees the data ends in a newline, so to get exactly what the user entered you want to get one less character than is in the widget, otherwise you will get this automatically inserted newline. For example:

```
self.outputText.get("1.0", "end-1c")
```